# Cut Off mode of an NPN transistor with PSPICE

Tags: transistors, npn, pspice, orcad

[image: N[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lU0G.png)

I am trying to model the cutoff mode of an NPN transistor with a switch that is connected to the base. Unfortunately, it shows current going through. I am using ORCAD Capture. [image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I should see zero current from the connector to the emitter.

I really don't know how the switch works in PSPICE. From what I found on the internet the symbol means that it opens at time t. Where should I define the time t? I googled and couldn't find an answer. The name of the switch is sw_tOpen and can be found in ANL_MISC library.

Comment: Are you sure that source is properly grounded? Move it around, see if the wires "stick".

Comment: Yes I am sure it is connected because it gives me the right numbers when I replace the switch with wire

Comment: You know, it would help you immensly to first learn, even a little bit about the tool you're about to use. Editing components should be part of the basics.

Comment: I am quite familiar with PSPICE and know what I am doing. I just have a question along the way, which no one could answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the net for the PSpice manual you'll eventually run into [this link](https://www.electronics-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/PSPCREF.pdf). I don't know the name of that switch, and it looks like it's not a current, or voltage controlled one, but with the manual you should be able to find it and its usage (I don't have PSpice).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. Since the switch closes at time=0s it shows the result for when the switch is closed. I had to use the current probe to see the current over time. It will go to zero after some nanoseconds.